# git add is accepted but git status doesn't show

Tags: git

`git add` command is adding files but `git status` doesn't show them.

I have a folder named `Dream Tech` and it's my local git repo. Every time I try to add these files by `git add .`, it shows

```
Pranavs-MacBook-Pro:Dream Tech pranavmishra$ git add .   
Pranavs-MacBook-Pro:Dream Tech pranavmishra$ git status   
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: And what files do you have to stage

Comment: they are html files and some jpg images

Comment: Are you sure those aren't in folders that are in .gitignore

Comment: I'm not sure but when i checked it shows                                                      Pranavs-MacBook-Pro:Dream Tech pranavmishra$ git check-ignore
fatal: no path specified

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output of `git status` is empty after `git add .`, then either there are no changes to your work tree (*i.e.*, no new files, no content changes to files already being tracked, and no permissions changes to files already being tracked) or changes happened in ignored files only.

Running `git add .` causes git to recursively scan the entire directory subtree looking for new files, content changes, or permissions changes to files. The [`git add` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) notes

> The `git add` command will not add ignored files by default. If any ignored files were explicitly specified on the command line, `git add` will fail with a list of ignored files. Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored.

To check whether one or more files that you believe have changes are actually ignored, run a command similar to

```
git check-ignore -v subdirectory1/foo.html subdirectory2/bar.jpg
```

Any output describes the ignore pattern that excluded each file. For example

```
$ git check-ignore -v subdirectory1/foo.html subdirectory2/bar.jpg
.gitignore:1:subdirectory2      subdirectory2/bar.jpg
```

This means that `bar.jpg` in `subdirectory2` is ignored by pattern `subdirectory2` in `.gitignore`.

Silence regarding `subdirectory1/foo.html` means that file is *not* being ignored.